# sort NSPopUpMenu items alphabetically

Tags: macos, cocoa, sorting, nsmenuitem, nspopupbutton

I want to sort the `NSMenuItem`s of a `NSPopUButton` alphabetically.
I checked the cocoa reference and i can't find a function that does this.
Am i missing something or i have to write my own sorting function? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to sort the items in place, you can however:

1. Use `itemArray` it get an array of all the items
2. Sort that array using one of the `NSArray` sort methods
3. Remove the existing items from the menu `removeAllItems`
4. Unfortunately there is no multiple add method so use a fast enumeration over your sorted array and `addItem:` each one.

Comment: that's what i figured out too. i used arrays like you said and did the job.
specifically i gathered the titles in an `NSMutableArray unsortedValues`
then  
`NSArray *sortedValues = [unsortedValues sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];`
(with NSPopUpButton = mymenu)
`[mymenu addItemsWithTitles:sortedValues];`

thank you for your reply btw :)